# Закрепить сайт в центре экрана

Tags: html, css

Народ, есть сайт (http://celldweller.org/, изначально его шаблон был резиновым (растягивался в зависимости от размеров экрана пользователя), но потом он был переделан в статический, и теперь он "липнет" к левому краю экрана.
Вот скриншот: http://celldweller.org/data/234234242342.jpg)
Я только начинаю осваивать искусство создания сайтов, это мой, можно так сказать, пробный проект, поэтому не злитесь сильно если код мой крив и сайт смотрится не очень.
Да, и еще один вопрос: не могли бы вы взглянуть на вот такой вариант дизайна сайта
(http://celldweller.org/data/newDesign/index.html) и высказать свое мнение о нем и сказать лучше он оригинала или хуже.

Comment: Второй дизайн симпотичнее. ИМХО

Comment: Второй лучше, не знаю чем даже... "радоснее", "уникальнее"...

Comment: (оффтоп) Celldweller - музыкальный коллектив, состоящий из одного человека - Скота Альберта  - Музыкальный коллектив из одного человека? :)

Comment: дизайны ужасные) я бы на таком сайте не остался, буть даже нетлешным фаном группы. За сдельную плату - нарисую и сверстаю дизайн, будет cool)))

Comment: Fatahan, да Клейтон единсвтенный участник группы, он пишет всю музыку и тексты + делает аранжировки, работает над клипами. Для концертов приглашает своих знакомых музыкантов из других коллективов и проектов. 
invincible - спасибо, будем дорабатывать.
Palmervan - спасибо за предложение, но так как проект делается для себя, что бы чему-то научиться, то хочу попробовать все сделать своими силами. Если когда-то буду претендовать на что-то серьезное, конечно же обращусь к помощи спецов типа Вас, еще раз спасибо за предложение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С таким же успехом можно сделать:

```
body {
width: 1024px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto; }
```

И не надо ни каких а-ля "главных" div'ов

Comment: Спасибо, джентльмены, Ваши советы оказались полезными и помогли мне.

Comment: здесь хватит и

    body{
    width: 1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }

Comment: Кто короче? =)

    body{width:1024px;margin:auto}

Answer (score 1):

Закидываете все в div#wrap.
Пишете в css: #wrap{width:1024px;margin:0 auto}.
...
PROFIT!

Answer (score 0):

margin: 0 auto; 
этот стиль выравнивает любой кусок кода по центру. (: